# xna animation issue

Tags: 3d, xna

i wanted to draw the 3 axis X Y Z and a model 
to see where is it in the space and how it moves

when i just draw the cube with a simple rotation 
everything is ok

but when i add axis drawing method

the rendring is not ok

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame2
{

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
    //Some declaration 
    float x = 30f;
    float y = 0f;
    float z = 30f;

    //GraphicsDevice device;
    VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
    VertexPositionColor[] lines;

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Model model;
    Matrix view;
    Matrix progection;
    float xTans = 0.0f;
    float yTans = 0.0f;
    float zTans = 0.0f;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        //device = graphics.GraphicsDevice;
        base.Initialize();
        this.IsMouseVisible = true;
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        model = Content.Load<Model>("cube");

        DrawLines();

        createCamera();

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == 
                ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);

        //update camera
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Azure);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect fx in mesh.Effects)
            {
                fx.View = view;

                //fx.World = Matrix.CreateRotationX(xTans);
                fx.World = Matrix.CreateRotationY(yTans);
                //fx.World = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(zTans);

                fx.Projection = progection;
                fx.EnableDefaultLighting();

            }
            mesh.Draw();

        }
        //xTans += 0.01f;
        yTans += 0.01f;
        //zTans += 0.01f;

        BasicEffect effect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

        effect.View = view;
        effect.Projection = progection;

        effect.World = Matrix.Identity;

        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            // Begin Drawing
            pass.Apply();
            // Set the vertex buffer to graphic device
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, 0);
            // Draw the axes with LineList Type
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
            PrimitiveType.LineList, lines, 0, 3);
            //pass.Apply();
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    protected void DrawLines()
    {
        lines = new VertexPositionColor[6];

        //Setting Size and Width and Color of the X axis
        lines[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(50, 0, 0), Color.Red);
        lines[1] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-50, 0, 0), Color.Red);

        //Setting Size and Width and Color of the Y axis
        lines[2] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 50, 0), Color.Green);
        lines[3] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, -50, 0), Color.Green);

        //Setting Size and Width and Color of the Z axis
        lines[4] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 50), Color.Blue);
        lines[5] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, -50), Color.Blue);

        vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(graphics.GraphicsDevice,
            VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration, 6, BufferUsage.None);
        vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(lines);
    }

    protected void createCamera()
    {
        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(
            new Vector3(0f, 60.0f, 60f), 
            Vector3.Zero, 
            Vector3.Up);
        progection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
            MathHelper.ToRadians(8.0f), 
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 
            10.0f, 
            1000.0f);
    }        
} //end game class
} //end namespace
```

the function that draws the axis is drawLines()

inside the method draw()

i have this to really draw the axes

```
BasicEffect effect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

effect.View = view;
effect.Projection = progection;

effect.World = Matrix.Identity;

foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    // Begin Drawing
    pass.Apply();
    // Set the vertex buffer to graphic device
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, 0);
    // Draw the axes with LineList Type
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
    PrimitiveType.LineList, lines, 0, 3);
    //pass.Apply();
}
```

i dont know why the speed of rendring of the rotation is slow

Comment: I flagged for 'too localized', but mostly because the 'doesn't belong here' won't offer gamedev as an option.  I realize it might not be appropriate there, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good news, and there is bad news.  The good news is that your project can be made to run smoothly.  You posted enough code to build your project, as long as the builder has an fbx model laying around like I did.  This the required change.

```
// take this out of your Draw() method.
BasicEffect effect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);

// put this in your class variables
BasicEffect effect;

//and put this at the end of LoadContent()
effect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
```

Explanation at the end of the post.

The bad news is that you have a large pile of code which is bad.  It will compile, and it will run, but it won't run well.  I assume you are somewhat new to writing an XNA project, which means you might have a general lack of understanding of the components of a game program.

And although I'm going to try to explain some of the things you have done wrongly, your post isn't really a good one for SO.  It's a result of simple poor practise, rather than a technical conundrum.  Over at [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), questions like this are sometimes accepted, as they make good examples for how (not) to program a game with a specific technology.  I am going to flag your post to be moved there when I'm done answering; the mods may decide it's not worthy of that.

Anyway, here's my best effort:

**You call this function in your load content method.**

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    ...
    DrawLines();
    ...
}
```

As the default template comments tell you, the load content method is for loading content.  Not for drawing.  It only gets called one time, so it's silly to draw a single frame from it anyway.  But that's not precisely what you're doing with that method.  You are declaring some primitive data in there.  That's ok, but the last two lines are superfluous:

```
protected void DrawLines()
{
    lines = new VertexPositionColor[6];
    lines[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(50, 0, 0), Color.Red);
    // ...

    vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(graphics.GraphicsDevice,
        VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration, 6, BufferUsage.None);
    vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(lines);
    ...
```

You don't even use that vertex buffer.  You use `DrawUserPrimitives<T>()`, which sets a vertex buffer for you.  Which means you also don't need this line from your draw method.

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, 0);
```

**You set your vertex data after beginning your effect pass.**

This is a bad idea.  Interrupting the graphics hardware after it has begun working.  This can frequently be a bottleneck in a game's performance.  It's not, in your case, but still a bad idea.

**You create a new effect every frame.**

As I wrote above, this is the only thing you need to change.  In spite of it's name, a `BasicEffect` is a complex OO container for a multitude of configurable shader fragments, as well as everything else that is required to draw complex geometry with multiple textures and materials and effects.  And you try to allocate one of those objects 60 times per second.

My advice is this:  read more [blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/), study more [example code](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=4&devarea=0&platform=0&sort=2), and learn to use [a memory profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).